# c++ Generic function to divide any data type?

Tags: c++, string, templates, generics, type-conversion

I'm trying to use a single function to divide the usual data types (int, double, float, long, string, char) and having trouble converting a generic string to numeric type. This is what I have so far:

```
template <typename T>
T const& Division(T const& a, T const& b)
{
    if (typeid(a) == typeid(string))
    {
        stringstream ss;
        float first, second;
        ss << a; 
        ss >> first;
        ss << b;
        ss >> second;

        stringstream output;
        output << first / second;
        T result;
        output >> result;

        return result;
    }   
}
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to use a single function to divide **any data generic** type"* - That doesn't sound good, your code attempt attests to that. What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: *Any* type? What if I define a Person class? What does `person1 / person2` mean? At best it will be nonsensical.

Comment: What kind of trouble? Please read about [mcve].

Comment: Isn't doing type specific stuff in an generic function considered bad practice?

Comment: @Dr. Fre Yes it is. If you need to be specific then you ought to *specialise* the template. Or adopt a different approach entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since division would always require nuances specific to your type, a generic template function is not a good approach.

But you could overload the division operator on a case by case basis. For example, for a class `Foo`, make sure that the prototype for this function is in the translation unit prior to use:

```
Foo operator/ (const Foo& numerator, const Foo& denominator){
    // ToDo - your code here, and return a newly constructed Foo.
}
```

That will also be syntactically more palatable at the calling site.